# HBase Column family locality

Tags: hbase, column-family

there are HBase on five servers with one Table that contains one column Family and I should do some `map` tasks on it per each key and save the result.
the main question is:

*to keep data locality* which one is better: create *new Column Family* on the existence Table or create *new Table*?

and the Next question:

*HBase Documentation* suggests keeping lower than three Column Family, and as I told I have more than ten `map` tasks and would to keep each result in new Column Family.what shall I do? because each `map` tasks are different from the other one. the **locality** preserving and *search cost* are important.

Comment: can you give a link to a documentation that tells about 3 column families per table?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, please consider this link _http://hbase.apache.org/1.2/book.html#number.of.cfs_

Comment: thanks for the link. Notice that this recommendation is mostly about writing to different CF. For reading it is not really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which one is better: create new Column Family on the existence Table
>   or create new Table

I would recommend to care more about schema and simplicity of table design, rather than trying to hack HBase internals to get the best performance. If information from these 2 column families is related and you need to access both CFs in map-reduce scans - keep them in same table. If information is 100% independent and you will never need to scan them simultaneously - keep them in different tables. Again, it's a schema design question, don't try to perform premature optimisations.

Second question - I did not understand what you're asing, sorry.